# Are android wallpapers persistent?

Tags: android, mobile, wallpaper, persistent

I have an application that sets the user's background.  Is it possible to remove the wallpaper if my app is uninstalled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe if you save the wallpaper image onto the user's device, whether storing the image on the SD card or elsewhere, it will stay on their device until *they* remove it.

Comment: fwiw, I accidentally deleted an image on my SD card that was set to my background. I was afraid I had done something bad but nothing happened. It maintained the background image, no problems, so it must store a temporary copy somewhere.

Comment: I had a problem where I had installed this horrible *lock screen* app where I had to connect the dots or something to unlock my phone. Needless to say, I uninstalled it but then I kept seeing it. Turns out, I had to disable the setting inside my phone to allow screen lock, so it had to still be on my system (*somewhere*) in-order to display it.